# How to get the handle of the Window that is parent of current C program?

Tags: winapi

My exact question is this: How to get the handle of the cmd.exe DOS Window of the console associated with the calling process? I need to use this from a console application program written in C executed from the command line that may have several active copies of itself in different console Windows (executed via START command).

I reviewed many times the Win32 API documentation. I tried with GetActiveWindow and does not work. I know that EnumWindows could be used for that, but this method fail if there are more than one active Window with the same title (BTW, change the Window title is NOT an option).

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [GetConsoleWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683175.aspx) function.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This function is NOT included in my old Win32 API documentation. I suppose I should update it...